# Python calling documentation of defined function

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I am a newbie to python. Just try to get the comments defined in function using *doc* but getting the error.

Here's my code:

```
def nam(i):
    """passing the name to
    a function"""
    print('hello  '+i+' good mornin')
```

And here's the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print(nam._doc_)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_doc_'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `_doc_` (single underline on each side) with `__doc__` (double underlines)

To illustrate, let's define your function and display the documentation:

```
>>> def nam(i):
...     """passing the name to
...     a function"""
...     print('hello  '+i+' good mornin')
... 
>>> nam.__doc__
'passing the name to\n    a function'
```

The method above works.  The method below, however, fails:

```
>>> nam._doc_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_doc_'
```

The reason is that `__doc__` needs two underline characters on each side, not just one.

#### Documentation

From the [python online documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-docstring):

> **docstring**
>  A string literal which appears as the first expression
>   in a class, function or module. While ignored when the suite is
>   executed, it is recognized by the compiler and put into the `__doc__`
>   attribute of the enclosing class, function or module. Since it is
>   available via introspection, it is the canonical place for
>   documentation of the object.

Comment: @sharma [What should you do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).